# Scala: Polymorphic daisy chaining

Tags: scala

```
class Foo(protected[this] val s: Iterator[String]) {
  def apply(it: Iterator[String]): Foo = new Foo(it ++ s)
}

class Bar(s: Iterator[String]) extends Foo(s) {

}
```

**Question:** How can I get `Bar.apply()` to return a `new Bar` instead of a `new Foo`? I don't want to override.

Comment: I simplified the example, there are a lot more methods that need to act in the same way and a lot of extending classes.

Comment: Why not extract `new Foo` in separate method and then override it (instead of overriding `apply`)? e.g. `protected def create(s: Iterator[String]): Foo = new Foo(s)`. You can also use a reflection (but it's probably something you don't want to do, not?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use F-bounded polymorphism to get an `apply` that returns the proper type. You also need to define a method that creates an instance of the subclass:

```
abstract class Foo[X](protected[this] val s: Iterator[String]) {
  self: X =>
  def newSubclass(s: Iterator[String]): X
  def apply(it: Iterator[String]): X = newSubclass(it ++ s)
}

class Bar(s: Iterator[String]) extends Foo[Bar](s) {
  def newSubclass(s: Iterator[String]): Bar = new Bar(s)
}
```

`Bar.apply` will have `Bar` as its return type, without needing to be overriden.

You can read more about F-bounded polymorphism at the [Twitter Scala school](http://twitter.github.io/scala_school/advanced-types.html#fbounded).

Comment: I thought F-bounded too, couldn't figure out how to reference the constructor. Kudos on the newSubclass, I was looking for Mjolnir to crack the nut.

Answer (score 0):

Have looked through [this](http://scalada.blogspot.com/2008/02/thistype-for-chaining-method-calls.html) article. Seems it's what you want. Quickly scetch out simple example(using `var`'s in this example)

```
class A(var s: String) {
  def apply(a: String): this.type = {
    s = "A" + a
    this
  }
}

class B(var s: String) extends A(s)
```

P.S.: Tried to use vals but it is impposible to call constructor in method which return type is `this.type`. Maybe you'll find the solution))

Comment: No, `this.type` won't do what you want. `this.type` doesn't refer to the class that `this` belongs to, instead, it is a way to say that a method returns `this`. The only value for `this.type` is `this`. It is mostly for use with fluent APIs combined with path-dependent types.